# Garbage collector performance on different machines

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I have a large memory consumption .NET 2.0 application. Ussually the GC handles the cleaning of the memory well.
However, I have a case where the application is installed in 2 different machines, one with 2gb of memory and one with 3gb of memory. In the 3gb of memory it crashes with Out Of Memory exception, while in the 2gb it nevers fails.
The .net runtime is the same in both machines and also the application installation is the same.
It is possible that when there is more memory the trigger to start the Grabage Collector is not raised on time?

Comment: We need a lot more than the RAM size on two machines. We need the operating system and also good deal of understanding what you do and what not. Do you handle a lot of unmanaged resources such as bitmap? Are you using any ORM? Are you using GC pinning of the memory?

Answer (score 3):

The amount of RAM has *nothing* to do with the amount of memory available to a .NET program.  All modern operating systems provide virtual memory.  On Windows, the typical amount of virtual memory available to a program is a bit less than 2 gigabytes.  There's a special boot option (/3GB) that increases that to 3 gigabytes, at a cost of taking addressable memory away from the operating system.  It doesn't work anymore on most modern machines, the video card tends to eat up too much addressable physical memory.  It isn't impossible to actually get less than 2GB because of this.

If the machine runs a 64-bit operating system then you'll get close to 4 gigabytes if the code runs in x86 mode.  And oodles of virtual memory in x64 mode, limited only by the maximum size of the paging file.

These virtual memory sizes are completely independent of the actual amount of RAM installed on the machine.  If you have less RAM than addressable virtual memory space, very common 15 years ago, then it is possible to invoke so-called 'paging file thrashing'.  You see the operating system trying to provide enough available RAM to honor the program's need to use too much virtual memory at the same time.  It swaps data between RAM and the paging file.  That can severely slow down the machine, you run out of patience before you run out of memory.

An OutOfMemoryException tells you that the program ran out of addressable virtual memory.  The most typical cause is not actually completely depleting all address space, it is running out of holes big enough to fit the object you're trying to allocate.  Virtual memory can become fragmented.  The SysInterals' VMMap utility can give you insight in how the virtual memory of your program is divvied-up.

Running out of virtual memory is quite difficult to deal with, it is essentially an asynchronous exception that you cannot recover from.  With the exception of doing something like loading a bitmap, the kind of object that requires lots of (unmanaged) memory and therefore almost always has trouble with finding a large enough hole.  In general, your program should never get any closer than using up half of the available space.  That's not usually difficult, a gigabyte is a lot of memory.  When your program's needs are fundamentally beyond that limit then you must specify a 64-bit operating system requirement for your program.  A two hundred dollar solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that GC will work if there is stuff to collect.  It sounds like you have some unknown memory leaks in code that are causing objects to be ignored by the GC, in other words, they aren't viable for collection according to the runtime.

Do you use a lot of events?

If you believe the GC is not collecting valid objects, you can force a collection (post-emptive defense: calling `GC.Collect` is hardly ever required and not a substitute for a memory profiling tool):

`GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y46kxc5e.aspx

If object's are ready to collect, they will be collected here.  I suspect that references to objects are being held, stopping the GC.

**Update:** of course outside the box, the machine running out of memory is not necessarily because of your program.  Does this other computer run a lot more stuff concurrently as opposed to the 2Gb computer?

Comment: Virtual -1. With the machine running out of memory, calling `GC.Collect` is obviously would not prove anything since it is way passed the thresholds of the GC.

Comment: Before the machine gets to that state you can call GC.Collect to see if it reduces your working set.  It was more a hidden argument to say that the GC is *very likely* not the thing failing, as was elluded in the OP.

Comment: The 3gb machine has not more stuff running consequently. It seems that the trigger for the collection execution is not called.

Comment: @Ariel seems strange, the GC would attempt to collect as the memory usage grows.  So by the time you get to a full 3Gb usage, GC would have run many times.  Is it possible that perhaps paging is disabled on this computer?  On the 2Gb computer, although it doesn't fail does performance noticeably degrade?

Comment: I will check the performance on the 2gb...how do I check if the paging is disabled?

Comment: @Ariel My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced tab -> Performance Settings button -> Advanced tab -> Change... button.  The settings are in here on Windows 7.